# Run command line instruction from inside fortran

Tags: fortran

I want to call a matlab script from inside a fortran code.

Directly from the command line I can do:
`"C:\path1\matlab.exe" -batch "addpath('C:\path2'); simulation"`

This will run the matlab script flawlessly.

Now the question is how to run the above from the inside of a Fortran script.

I tried:

`call execute_command_line("C:\path1\matlab.exe" -batch "addpath('C:\path2'); simulation")`

and

`call execute_command_line(""C:\path1\matlab.exe" -batch "addpath('C:\path2'); simulation"")`

But neither of the above work, since it seems that I need to put the instruction using `" "`. But this messes up the remaining double quotes on the instruction.

Comment: You can use single quotes inside the string.

Comment: The linked question does have answers for your situation: to include a double quote within double quote delimiter string you'll want to start `execute_command_line("""C:\path` etc.